# SoapUI, Rest: how to avoid parameters encoding in REST request URI in soapui?

Tags: rest, get, soapui, postman

In Postman, I'm successully sending Get/Rest "as it is", e.g.:

```
http://host:4444/api/someaction?x=1&y=A;B&date=01/02/2018
```

But in SoapUI, it's transferred to

```
http://host:4444/api/someaction?x=1&y=A%3BB&date=01%2F02%2F2018
```

So, question is: how to avoid this encoding in URI, and send request equally to Postman?

---

Just note below(not related directly to the question):

Finding answer is important here, because there is additional token coming in response, and, , we are receiving different tokens using Postman, and SoapUI(I guess, because of this encoding), and this makes unavailable any further automation tryings(using SOAPUI), for current API I'm working on.

Comment: Can you clarify the question please? Are you not wanting the URL to be encoded?

Comment: Is the response received in SoapUI not the desired one?

Comment: @DannyDainton yes. Rao yes, response is not desired.

Comment: Can you attach more details to the question please? Screenshots of Postman etc. Are you getting a specific error message? I still don’t really understand "send the request equally to Postman" - do you mean using Postman?

Comment: sorry, Danny, will do when can. Unfortunately, its bit disclosed... Commonly, I just ment, that when sending in Postman - URI it's not encoded, and sends fine. But when sending in soapui (after adding rest URI just from postman) - URI encoded in Raw. Also there is a point - interesting, why responses can be different? (and they are different)/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found answer directly on question "how to avoid parameters encoding" - we just can turn it off when configuring REST parameters:

[image]

But there is other trouble - still different responses for same requests, made from POSTMAN and SoapUI.

I will mark this question as asked by myself (if no better answers in 2 days), and will ask separately about request configuring.